# Psycopg2 SQL Statment is working from the query Builder but not from Python

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, postgresql-9.2, psycopg2

The statement I want to use is the following:

```
UPDATE table SET colum1 = 1  WHERE colum2 LIKE '%gasse%';
```

when I use exactly this statement everything containing `gasse` gets updated but when I do this in python with Psycopg2:

```
sqlstring = """UPDATE table SET colum1 = 1  WHERE colum2 LIKE '%gasse%';"""
cur.execute(sqlstring)
```

colum1 does not get updated have i done something wrong did i not escape something correctly?

Comment: You may only have done this to illustrate your current query, but it is always best practice to send over your parameters separately. Always. By doing so, you also do not need to worry about correctly escaping the data inside the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to `commit` the transaction that is automatically opened by Psycopg before the first command

```
connection.commit()
```

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html